# Hibernate não considera campo para insert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, chave-composta

Tenho uma classe `Cliente` que possui chave composta:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Clientes")
@IdClass(ClientePK.class)
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    //@EmbeddedId
    //private ClientePK clientePK;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id_Cliente", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private long idCliente;

    @Id
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Loja", nullable = false)
    private Loja loja;

}

public class ClientePK implements Serializable {

    private long idCliente;
    private Loja loja;
}
```

Em seguida tenho uma classe `ClienteHistorico` que também contém chave composta.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “Clientes_Historicos”)
@IdClass(ClienteHistoricoPK.class)
public class ClienteHistorico implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Resolvable(colName = "Id. Cliente Histórico")
    @Column(name = "Id_Cliente_Historico", nullable = false)
    private Long idClienteHistorico;

    @Id
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Loja", nullable = false)
    private Loja loja;

    @Resolvable(colName = "Cliente")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente", referencedColumnName = "Id_Cliente", nullable = false, insertable = true)
        ,
        @JoinColumn(name = "loja", referencedColumnName = "loja", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @MapsId("loja")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Cliente cliente;

}
```

Utilizei a anotação `@MapsId("loja")` para indicar que o campo `loja` da chave primária deverá ser utilizado com o próprio campo FK da ligação com cliente.

Ocorre que ao realizar o insert em `ClienteHistorico` o campo `cliente` não está sendo levado em consideração para ser inserido.

> ```
> Informações:   Hibernate: insert into Clientes_Historicos (Data, Tipo, Usuario, Id_Cliente_Historico, Loja) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
> WARN:   SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
> ERROR:   ORA-01400: não é possível inserir NULL em ("MARTINELLO"."CLIENTES_HISTORICOS"."ID_CLIENTE")
>
> Informações:   HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
> ERROR:   HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
> ```

Comment: Eu tentaria o seguinte: 1) Descomente o `clientePK` e sua anotação; 2) Anote a classe `ClientePK` com @Embeddable e coloque nela as anotações dos campos, depois apagando esses campos da classe `Cliente` (você quer apenas o `clientePK` descomentado  lá); 3) na classe `ClienteHistorico`, apague as anotações de _join_ e `@Resolvable`, e modifique o `@mapsId` para "clientePK". Veja se funciona.

Comment: @StatelessDev desta forma ele gera dois novos campos. CLIENTE_ID_CLIENTE E CLIENTE_LOJA quando na verdade eu preciso que ele aproveite o campo Loja da Classe Cliente_Historicos